# Using at (@) symbol in URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, mailchimp

**The Scenario**

I'm using MailChimp to send someone to a landing page, and appending their email address to the URL like so http://example.com?email=someone@test.com

I then intend to use Javascript to grab the email address from the URL.

**The Problem**

According to URL best practices, you're apparently not supposed to use the @ symbol in URLs unless it's for its intended purpose (username@password).

Seeing as I am using MailChimp to insert the email address, **I cannot encode the @ character using % symbol**.

Is there likely to be a scenario in any browser that will reject the use of this @ symbol or mess things up in some way? Or is it just "not best practice"? I've tested it in a few browsers and seems to be fine, but just want to be sure.

Comment: _"Is there likely to be a scenario in **any** browser"_... Probably.

Comment: What about using `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()`

Comment: @anto.nishanth if you read my question, you'll notice that I'm using Mailchimp, and do not have access to PHP or any other scripting language to affect the URL.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is this question invalid? Strange community this has become.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered your own question.  Test in the browsers you care about. Some will in fact get messed up, but they are nowadays irrelevant, unless you for some reason want to support them.

Comment: Is that purely a browser version thing though? I figured there might be other factors involved.

Comment: @3Dom the thing about browsers is sometimes they are "nicer" that the spec and allow things that "aren't best practice" as long as they are not ambiguous; but other times they don't fully implement the spec, or just make a judgement call based on their release schedules etc.  So as you noted, it does work fine in major modern browsers, but if you want to support android browser 2.0, you'll have to test.

Comment: Great, thanks for that. I think you've answered my question. Basically test every browser you want to support, because browser age is no guarantee. Guess I'll get testing then.